# Exposing Contract first SOAP Webservice with spring-boot and Weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, spring-ws

I am trying to expose Contract First SOAP Webservice with spring-boot and Weblogic. Its a Gradle based setup and i am using following dependencies for generation of JAXB classes.

```
 jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11'
 jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
 jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11'
 jaxb 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12-b141001.1542'
 compile(files(genJaxb.classesDir).builtBy(genJaxb))
```

I have a static response XML which i am sending as a response. The XML is first unmarshalled and then return. Now the problem here is response XML elements are coming with namespace prefixes which i want to avoid as on the client side it is causing some issue which i am not aware of as i dont have access to that system.

Could you please suggest on how i can control marshalling process used by Spring framework to avoid the prefix generation?

Thanks and Regards,
HG